# get today date in java

Tags: java, date, timestamp

This is my database:

```
date          status
1343469690     Q
1343470540     C
1343470556     P
```

I have written this code:

```
public class TodayQ {

    public int data() {
        int count = 0;
        //count++;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pro", "root", "");

            PreparedStatement statement = con.
                    prepareStatement("select * from orders where status='Q' AND date=CURDATE()");
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            while (result.next()) {
                // Do something with the row returned.
                count++; //if the first col is a count.
            }
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

It works successfully when date is in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. But now my date is a timestamp in `1343469690` format. How is get the count value?

Comment: Where is the code to "get" the date? Are you seeing any error/exception?

Comment: What _exactly_ is the problem? _In what way_ doesn't it work?

Comment: t works successfully when date is in yyyy-mm-dd format. But now my date is a timestamp in 1343469690 format. How is get the count value in dis timestamp format ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's actually a Timestamp, then you have the date: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html. Converting a TimeStamp to a Calendar (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) is trivial: see the Calendar.setTimeInMillis() method.

Comment: how is call the above method in my code...i can't understand.please give me some solutions

Answer (score 0):

Replace **CURDATE()** into **FROM_UNIXTIME()** .According to your code, you should change likes this;

```
      PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select * from orders where status='Q' AND date=FROM_UNIXTIME(date,'%Y %M %D')");
```

See reference [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).

Comment: the following exception is displayed on console:Syntax error or access violation message from server: "Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'FROM_UNIXTIME'"
0

Comment: now only i have to insert 2 orders..then it is have to display the count value is 2.but the displaye dcount value is 0

Comment: hi display the count value is 0 only.